# How to display master variables in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, master-detail

I have a master-detail relationship with master object Service__c and child object Service_Task__c. The relationship API is Service_Task__r. I am using a custom controller.

My visualforce page is displaying a list of Service_Task__c. However, for each Service_Task__c, I want to show a variable from the master object Service__c which is Description__c. How do i access the variable Description__c and display it?

`serviceTaskList = [SELECT Name, Service__c FROM Service_Task__c}`

I have tried this and it shows the Service__c ID. `Service__c.Description__c` does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the "relationship" to get the parent record. For standard fields, this is the name of the field minus the Id (e.g. to get the account name on a contact, Account.Name), and for custom fields, as in your example, you change __c to __r (e.g. Service__r.Description__c).